# How to copy contents of an Object into an already defined object?

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, copy-constructor

I have an object called `Grid` which is evolving in my main script. This is how I have defined `Grid`:

```
class Grid{

public:
    std::vector <Polymer> PolymersInGrid;                 // all the polymers in the grid 
    std::vector <Particle> SolventInGrid;                 // solvent molecules in the grid 
    const int x;                                          // length of x-edge of grid 
    const int y;                                          // length of y-edge of grid 
    const int z;                                          // length of z-edge of grid 
    const double kT;                                      // energy factor 
    const double Emm ;                                    // monomer-monomer interaction 
    const double Ess ;                                    // solvent-solvent interaction 
    const double Ems_n ;                                  // monomer-solvent when Not aligned 
    const double Ems_a ;                                  // monomer-solvent when Aligned

    double Energy; 
    std::map <std::vector <int>, Particle> OccupancyMap;     // a map that gives the particle given the location
    

    Grid(int xlen, int ylen, int zlen, double kT_, double Emm_, double Ess_, double Ems_n_, double Ems_a_): x (xlen), y (ylen), z (zlen), kT (kT_), Emm(Emm_), Ess (Ess_), Ems_n (Ems_n_), Ems_a (Ems_a_) {        // Constructor of class
        // this->instantiateOccupancyMap(); 
    };


    // Destructor of class 
    ~Grid(){                                    

    }; 
...
};
```

In my main script, my Grid evolves when I apply an operator to Grid.

```
    Grid G = CreateGridObject(positions, topology);

    std::cout << "Energy of box is: " << G.Energy << std::endl;
    
    for (int i{0}; i<NumberOfMoves; i++){
        // perform evolution
        Grid G_test (BackwardReptation(G, 0)); 

        // check if G_test is a good structure
        if (G_test is good){ 
        // assign
        G = G_test; 
        }
    }
```

When I do this, I get the error
`object of type 'Grid' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted. copy assignment operator of 'Grid' is implicitly deleted because field 'x' is of const-qualified type 'const int'`.

I need to evolve Grid multiple times, check if it is good at each evolution step, and change its contents. How can I do this given that I want the geometry of Grid and the energy surface (`Emm, Ess, Ems_n, Ems_a`) are to be held `const`?

**edit:**
The following addition to my classobject worked:

```
    Grid& operator=(const Grid& t){
        return *this; 
    }
```

I understand that & is an overloaded operator, can be used to refer to addresses of variables, can be used for rvalues, lvalues. My question is, how does one read the syntax `Grid& operator=`? What does Grid& mean?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can't change const values.

Comment: @S.M. i have made small edit. i apologize if this is a basic question.

Comment: You might need a introductory textbook about C++ if you do not know what reference is. C++ can't be learned by trial and error and guessing ... it is bit too complex.

Comment: You won't be able to copy objects of type `Grid` unless you write a copy constructor and a copy assignment for your `Grid` class. They will be deleted because you are defining a destructor. Check the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: *"How can I do this given that I want the geometry of Grid and the energy surface (Emm, Ess, Ems_n, Ems_a) are to be held const?"* -- what exactly is the "this" that you want to do? (All we know is that it is the result of some function called `BackwardReptation`.) Can you assure us that the "this" that you want to do should change only the non-const members of `Grid`? (If so, it seems like your `Grid` class encompasses two concepts, so potentially should be split into two classes.)

Comment: *"I understand that & is an overloaded operator, can be used to refer to addresses of variables, can be used for rvalues, lvalues. My question is, how does one read the syntax Grid& operator=? What does Grid& mean?"* -- As you wrote, `&` can be used for lvalues. Why the confusion?

Comment: @JaMiT I want to take all the components of G_test and give them to G. I create G_test because I am not sure the update I perform on G is a good one or not.

Comment: @bad_chemist If "give them to G" involves changing the geometry or energy surface of `G`, then your goal is at odds with your desire to keep those constant.

Comment: It does not involve changing the geometry of ```G```. Only the other components, like ```PolymersInGrid, SolventInGrid, OccupancyMap and Energy```.

Comment: @bad_chemist Then write a copy assignment operator that tells your compiler that only those fields will change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C++, can a class with a const data member not have a copy assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60535091/in-c-can-a-class-with-a-const-data-member-not-have-a-copy-assignment-operator)

Comment: I assume the `const` members are invariants, right? As in: they would be the same across all the instances of `Grid`? If so you can make them static, then default the copy-assignment operator with `Grid& operator =(Grid const&) = default;` otherwise you'll need to leave those members mutable.