# How erase & remove_if works whith const vector? (error C2678)

Tags: c++

I've been struggling with the behavior caused by next code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_value;

    A(std::string name, int value) : m_name{ name }, m_value { value }
    {
    }
};

auto main() -> int
{
   const std::vector<A> values{
       A("1 Hello", 1),
       A("2 Hello" , 2),
       A("3", 3),
       A("4", 4),
       A("5 Hello" , 5),
   };

   const auto removeIf = std::remove_if(
     values.begin(),
     values.end(),
     [](const A& m) { return m.m_value == 1 || m.m_value == 2 || m.m_value == 5; });

   const_cast<std::vector<A>&>(values)
     .erase(removeIf, values.end());
}
```

It does not compile since I got next error message

> error C2678: binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const A' (or there is no acceptable conversion) could be 'A &A::operator =(A &&)' or 'A &A::operator =(const A &)'

So I implemented the first option:

```
class A
{
public:
  std::string m_name;
  int m_value;

  A(std::string name, int value) : m_name{ name }, m_value{ value }
  {
  }

  // *** I ONLY ADDED THIS ***
  const A& operator=(const A& o) const
  {
    return o;
  }
};
```

But it is not working since at the end vector `values` has items 1 & 2:

```
{m_name="1 Hello" m_value=1 }
{m_name="2 Hello" m_value=2 }
```

when it should have items 3 & 4.

So here I'd love if you could help me to answer these questions:

1. Why do I need to overload the operator `=`? My guess is that it is required by `remove_if` because `values` is `const`, is that right?
2. Why is the overloading causing this to not work properly? I don't get it.
3. Is there any way to make it work without const_casting `values` first? because I only made it work const_casting first to avoid being forced to implement the overloading:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
  std::string m_name;
  int m_value;

  A(std::string name, int value) : m_name{ name }, m_value{ value }
  {
  }
};

auto main() -> int
{
  const std::vector<A> values{
      A("1 Hello", 1),
      A("2 Hello" , 2),
      A("3", 3),
      A("4", 4),
      A("5 Hello" , 5),
  };

  std::vector<A>& editValues = const_cast<std::vector<A>&>(values);

  const auto removeIf = std::remove_if(
    editValues.begin(),
    editValues.end(),
    [](const A& m) { return m.m_value == 1 || m.m_value == 2 || m.m_value == 5; });

  editValues
    .erase(removeIf, editValues.end());
}
```

With this, I get the expected values:

```
{m_name="3" m_value=3 }
{m_name="4" m_value=4 }
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Error messages sometimes show internal details when the code that’s being compiled is wrong. Here, trying to remove things from a `const` vector simply doesn’t make sense. You can play whack-a-mole for hours, changing code in response to symptoms, and not make any progress fixing the actual problem. Get rid of the `const`.

Comment: Your assignment operator makes no sense. It says "When I write `a = b`, I want to you leave `a` unchanged." When things don't make sense, the results don't make sense. (The `remove_if` function copies elements, and your assignment operator says "Nah, don't copy anything." So naturally, the copies are all messed up. But why are you trying to trick the compiler into thinking that it modified a `const` vector?)

Comment: Thanks Pete. I did that in my working example at the end using const_cast because I just can't get rid of const easily in the real codebase I'm working on.

Comment: This is UB whether you `const_cast` or not. The vector object (not the objects it contains) is const and it can't be altered after it's created w/o UB. It's actually possible to legally alter the contents of one of the contained objects by casting since they are not const. But you cannot legally alter the vector object which includes things like the number of contained objects.

Comment: `const A& operator=(const A& o) const` -- Your implementation of this function will just lead to bugs that are going to be hard to find.  Not only does it *not* do real copies, the copy constructor (which you did not implement) will do the right thing, while your user-defined assignment operator will do something different.  This is the case regardless if the object were `const` or not.

Comment: Perhaps you can make a copy of the vector and modify that (or make a fresh one, reserve space, and copy over the values you want).

Comment: Thanks @doug. Yeah I know & agree it shouldn't be modified but the code is already erasing all the items in this way for some cases so I was only asked to add remove_if for other cases. Or we'd change thousands of lines which PMs don't want lol

Comment: While you can't alter the vector w/o UB, you can destruct it and replace it with a new const vector as long as the type is the same. At least for c++>=20  The new vector can have different contents. If you are interested I can dig up a link discussing this. Oh, and the vector has to be a member of a class or struct. Not a top, stand alone object.

Comment: Sure! I mean, everything is really appreciated and useful for people that's coming from other languages (newbies in c++) like me lol

Comment: @Carlos these kinds of problems happen with seasoned C++ devs too. I had a lot of `const` correctness issues in the codebase I inherited from people writing in C++ for over 2 decades. PMs cause these to fester till they blow up in everyone's faces.

Comment: @Carlos these kinds of problems happen with seasoned C++ devs too. I had a lot of `const` correctness issues in the codebase I inherited from people writing in C++ for over 2 decades. PMs cause these to fester till they blow up in everyone's faces.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71848927/5282154) for a way to change const members of a class.  Note that if the class contains objects with any non-trivail destructors you need the ``std::destroy_at` call. It's superfluous otherwise.

Comment: *using const_cast because I just can't get rid of const easily in the real codebase* Looks like your problem has a larger scope. Part of the code says "Don't touch this", but your part of the code says "Nah, that's a silly prohibition", your project is going to blow up in your face rather sooner than later.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: After reading the answer again, the tone seems a bit rude. It was not my intention but it came out sounding like that**

1. Yes (and no, details below), you had to override `=` operator. Because of `const`.
2. It is not working properly because your overloaded function is wrong.
3. Yes, there is a way to do this. Dont make `values` `const` if you are going to modify them in the future

**There are all sorts of problems with your code** because `values` are marked const. So, you are invoking undefined behavior. From cppreference.com:

> Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior.

**Why does the first one fail?**
The canonical signature for `=` also known as the assignment operator is either `A& operator=(A o)` or `A& operator=(A const & o)` for copy assignment or `A& operator=(A&& o)` for move assignment operator. `const A& operator=(const A& o) const` is not an assignment operator. Let me explain.

1. `=` operator stands for assignment which means you are going to assign value of `o` it `this`
2. In `const A& operator=(const A& o) const`, the rightmost `const` means this function does not modify `this`. How can you assign `o` to `this` without modifying `this`? This is not possible so you are simply returning `o`. You broke the contract of `std::remove_if`, which thinks `=` means assignment.
3. In `const A& operator=(const A& o) const`. The middle `const`, this function will not modify `o`. You probably had to add it because `values` is const so all objects in it are also `const`. Without that `remove_if` would have failed because it moves removed objects to the end of the list using `=` where the right-hand side of the expression is `const`. Because `values` is `const`
4. In `const A& operator=(const A& o) const`. the leftmost `const` means this function returns a reference to `const` objects. You probably had to add it because `values` is const so all objects in it are also `const`. Without that `remove_if` would have failed because it moves removed objects to the end of the list using `=` where the left-hand side of the expression is `const`. Because `values` is `const`.

**Why does the second one work?**
You got lucky. Marking `std::vector` as `const` does not make the underlying memory const which would happen in some cases of `std::array` or constant string literals on some platforms. In which case you would have triggered an access violation from the memory management unit or a CPU trap or in the worst you might have launched nukes. So, when you casted away `const` in this scenario, the memory was perfectly modifiable because it was on the heap which is read-write memory. The compiler saw the use of `=` in `std::remove_if` and in the absence of your flawed custom `=` override generated the correct form of `=` which in this case was `A& operator=(A&& o)` or move assignment operator.